# How to output json data in controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angularjs and i want to ouput some json data on console.

I am doing something like this

```
$scope.events = events.query();
```

but when i print on the console

```
console.log($scope.events);
```

it gives me the output like

```
Array []
```

how can i print the data like this

```
[
  {"id":18,"file":{"url":"/uploads/playlist/file/18/01_-_MashAllah.mp3"},"event_id":23,"created_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z","updated_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z","name":"01 - MashAllah.mp3"}, 
  {"id":19,"file":{"url":"/uploads/playlist/file/19/02_-_Laapata.mp3"},"event_id":19,"created_at":"2015-11-11T10:50:01.000Z","updated_at":"2015-11-11T10:50:01.000Z","name":"02 - Laapata.mp3"}
]
```

below is my whole code

```
.controller('ShowEventsCtrl', ['$scope','events', function($scope,events) {

  $scope.events = events.query();
  console.log($scope.events);

 }]);
```

services

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('events', ['$resource',function($resource) {
    return $resource('/events', {},{
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    })
}])
```

and when i print the data in html like this

```
<div ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
  {{playlist}}
</div>
```

I get the correct output so i but how to output it in console.

Comment: Are you sure that `events.query()` is returning some data?

Comment: @RahulDesai when i print the same in html it gives me the correct output

Comment: Please show all code context. It sounds like you have an asynchronous operation fetching data and are trying to log the data before it is received

Comment: `$resource` is asynchronous, you need to use callback to access your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `events.query()` method is asynchronous, you need to log stuff after the action is resolved. Easiest way I can think of is

```
$scope.events = events.query(function(events) {
    console.log(events);
});
```

From [`$resource`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage)

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:
>
> - HTTP GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])`
>
> ...
>
> Success callback is called with (value, responseHeaders) arguments

---

I'm guessing your confusion comes from this feature of `$resource`

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

You see the correct data in your template because once the data is returned from the server, a scope digest is triggered and your template is updated.